# How to read date in custom format from csv file?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am parsing a csv file having data as

```
03-10-2016,18:00:00,2,6
```

When I am reading file creating schema as below

```
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(
                DataTypes.createStructField("Date", DataTypes.DateType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("Time", DataTypes.TimestampType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("CO(GT)", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("PT08.S1(CO)", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)))
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv").option("Date", "dd-MM-yyyy").schema(schema).load("src/main/resources/AirQualityUCI/sample.csv");
```

Its producing below error as

```
Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:137)
```

I feel that it is due to date format error. What are the ways of converting them into specific formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dateFormat` option when reading the CSV file(s) as follows:

```
val csvs = spark.
  read.
  format("csv").
  option("dateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy"). // <-- should match 03-10-2016
  load(...)
```

The default for `dateFormat` is `yyyy-MM-dd` so it's no surprise you've got the parsing error.

---

Quoting from the javadoc of [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-):

> **Throws** `IllegalArgumentException` - if the date given is not in the JDBC date escape format (yyyy-[m]m-[d]d)

That means that the value is incorrect for the parser of `valueOf`.

I'd have two recommendations here:

1. Read the dataset and `show` it to see what you have inside.
2. Use `dateFormat` option to define the proper format (it's `yyyy-MM-dd` by default)

Find more about the format patterns in [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`).

Comment: Can I use map function here which while parsing the csv data it will use `dataFormat` on string and convert it into required format and then create data set out of it. Just curious.

Comment: You can, but don't do things Spark could do for you (unless you're sure you can do them better).

Comment: Sure.I am big fan of yours and have read your wonderful notes named "Mastering Spark".They are very much helpful in learning it :)

Comment: Is there any elaborated details or link available on using `option`?

Comment: Working on one. Haven't found anything worth mentioning yet.