# How to read time in custom format from csv file?

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am parsing a csv file having data as:

```
2016-10-03, 18.00.00, 2, 6
```

When I am reading file creating schema as below:

```
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(
                DataTypes.createStructField("Date", DataTypes.DateType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("Time", DataTypes.TimestampType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("CO(GT)", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("PT08.S1(CO)", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)))

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv").schema(schema).load("src/main/resources/AirQualityUCI/sample.csv");
```

Its producing below error as:

```
Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:137)
```

I feel that it is due to time format error. What are the ways of converting them into specific formats or changes to be made into `StructType` for its proper meaning?

The format I expect is in form of hh:mm:ss as it will be helpful via spark sql to convert it into timestamp format by concatenating columns.

```
2016-10-03, 18:00:00, 2, 6
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295879/how-to-read-date-in-custom-format-from-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read both Date and Time as string, then you can easily merge and convert them to a Timestamp. You do not need to change "." to a ":" in the Time column as the format can be specified when creating the Timestamp. Example of an solution in Scala:

```
val df = Seq(("2016-10-03", "00.00.17"),("2016-10-04", "00.01.17"))
  .toDF("Date", "Time")

val df2 = df.withColumn("DateTime", concat($"Date", lit(" "), $"Time"))
  .withColumn("Timestamp", unix_timestamp($"DateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"))
```

Which will give you:

```
+----------+--------+-------------------+----------+
|      Date|    Time|           DateTime| Timestamp|
+----------+--------+-------------------+----------+
|2016-10-03|00.00.17|2016-10-03 00.00.17|1475424017|
|2016-10-04|00.01.17|2016-10-04 00.01.17|1475510477|
+----------+--------+-------------------+----------+
```

Of course, if you want you can still convert the Time column to use ":" instead of ".". It can be done by using `regexp_replace`:

```
df.withColumn("Time2", regexp_replace($"Time", "\\.", ":"))
```

If you do this before converting to a Timestamp, you need to change the specified format above.